# Re-write this query without temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

Learning SQL now, not particular big of temp table, since you have to drop each time you run your query. Basically this query below pulls info from patientinfo table and put into a temp table, then can be used to possibly join with another table Anyway to modify this query, so I don't need to use temp tables? Like I mean anyway to pull info from the table without a temp table, like that part where I commented out (into)

```
SELECT PatientCode [Code]
     , PatientID [Pltid]        
     , CASE WHEN PatientStatus = 'R' THEN 'lefthospital'
            WHEN PatientStatus = 'I' THEN 'StillIn'
            ELSE 'unknown' END [CDStatus]
INTO #PatientInfoPull    
FROM PatientInfo

   
SELECT PatientInfo.*       
FROM #initCDPull
```

Comment: Just don't put it into a temp table in the first place? Your example isn't clear why you have a temp table in the first place. Your second query clearly doesn't work because 'PatientInfo` doesn't exist.

Comment: So... why are you using a temp table? Nothing is clear about what you are asking, try adding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clearly explaining your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this query below pulls info from patientinfo table and put into a temp table, then can be used to possibly join with another table

Okay, you're doing something like this:

```
 SELECT <fields>
 INTO #SomeTemp
 FROM SomeReal
 WHERE SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'

 SELECT *
 FROM SomeOtherReal r
 JOIN #SomeTemp t ON r.SomeOtherColumn = t.SomeOtherColumn
```

In that case, you can use a sub-query (formally: "Derived Table") like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeOtherReal r
JOIN (
    SELECT <fields>
    FROM SomeReal
    WHERE SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'
) t ON r.SomeOtherColumn = t.SomeOtherColumn
```

or a Common Table Expression (CTE) like this:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT <fields>
    FROM SomeReal
    WHERE SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'
)
SELECT *
FROM SomeOtherReal r
JOIN t ON r.SomeOtherColumn = t.SomeOtherColumn
```

Even more than that, you can usually combine the steps like this:

```
SELECT t.<fields>, r.<fields>
FROM SomeOtherReal r
JOIN SomeReal t ON t.SomeOtherColumn = r.SomeOtherColumn
WHERE t.SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'
```